# Can an app be on your device but not on any screen?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod

I downloaded an app recently and when I was moving it from the screen it was placed after download; to another screen then I accidentally hovered over another app and made a folder. When I took it out of the folder I hovered over the section between the current screen and the next then I let go and the app had vanished (The app wasn't visible in any folders near the spot I hovered). I checked both screens. So I had to delete and re-install the app by going to settings and finding it on the storage menu. When I went to the app store and looked at purchased apps it was there and it had the open button but, it wasn't visible on any of my screens. Has this happened before?

Specs of situation:
- Using iPod 5 
- iOS 9.3.5
- App downloaded: Google Authenticator

Answer (score 1):

No... not permanently. [It's possible you ran into this iOS 9 glitch](https://lifehacker.com/hide-apps-in-ios-9-with-a-folder-trick-1751131506), but the app should appear upon restart.

> Create a folder with all the apps you want to hide away. While the
>   apps are still jiggling, drag the icon one page at a time until you
>   get to a blank page then let go. Attempt to drag the icon one more
>   page over from the blank page, then tap the home button.